# How can I stop Apple Music (via Music on macOS) from playing "related" songs after an album is complete?

Tags: macos, music, apple-music

- I open an album in Music (v1.3.4.56) on macOS.

  - Note: I have an active Apple Music subscription and am listening via Apple Music.
- I double-click the first song and start listening.
- When the album is done, it starts up what I assume is a "playlist based on the album you just finished".

Instead, when it finishes playing what I asked for, I want the music to stop. I'll pick a new album if and when I want to listen to something else.

Can I stop this behavior? If so, how? I didn't see a setting for it.

I realize I could probably select "repeat all" and hear the album over and over. No, I'd rather the needle come up off of the album and not play again.

---

Aka, "I'm sure many love it, but please don't play Joe Bonamassa's *Blues of Desperation* without asking after I've listened to Larkin Poe's *Reskinned*. I'd rather hear silence. Please & thanks."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn off AutoPlay - that's the 'infinity icon' in the Playing Next menu. https://support.apple.com/guide/music/use-the-playing-next-queue-musb1e6d1c76/mac

[image: screenshot of autoplay location]